# How to mock a function that returns a function using jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am trying to mock the function that returns another function. However, I am not sure how to get this done using jest. Thanks in advance.

1. Should return successfully.
2. Should throw an error.

Module needed to be mocked:

```
const initGreeter = () =>{
    return {
        sayHello: (name:string) =>{
            console.log(`Hello: ${name}`)
        }
    }
}
export default initGreeter;
```

The module under test:

```
import initGreeter from './greeter';

export const greetSomeone = (name:string) =>{
    const greeter = initGreeter();
    greeter.sayHello(name)
}
```

Tests:

```
import initGreeter from '../../utils/greeter';
import { greetSomeone } from '../../utils/greeterConsumer';

describe('greeterConsumer', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('greeter consumer should call SayHello on greeter', () => {
    //TODO:mock greeter here
    greetSomeone('sam');
    expect(greeter.sayHello.mock.call[0][0]).toBe('sam');
  });

  it('greeter consumer throws exception', () => {
    //TODO:mock greeter here so it throws exception
    expect(greetSomeone('sam')).toThrow(Error);
  });
});
```

**Please note code in Update 1 and 2 are a continuation of the code in the solution from @slideshowp2.**

**Update 2:** Looks like if the change the code below

```
jest.mock('./greeter', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => mGreeter);
});
```

to

```
jest.mock('../../utils/greeter.ts', () => ({  
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn(() => mGreeter)

}));
```

it works.

There are other ways to make the code from @slideshowp2 to work as is,  for example setting "esModuleInterop": true in tsconfig. However, I don't fully understand why it works for either case. I may check in the future and update here.

**Update 1:** after implementing the solution from @slideshowp2

I am getting the error below in my test

FAIL  src/**tests**/utils/greeterConsumer.test.ts
● greeterConsumer › greeter consumer should call SayHello on greeter

```
TypeError: greeter_1.default is not a function

  2 | 
  3 | export const greetSomeone = (name:string) =>{
> 4 |     const greeter = initGreeter();
    |                     ^
  5 |     greeter.sayHello(name)
  6 | }

  at Object.<anonymous>.exports.greetSomeone (src/utils/greeterConsumer.ts:4:21)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/utils/greeterConsumer.test.ts:18:5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) to mock `../../utils/greeter` module manually.

E.g.

`greeter.ts`:

```js
const initGreeter = () => {
  return {
    sayHello: (name: string) => {
      console.log(`Hello: ${name}`);
    },
  };
};
export default initGreeter;
```

`greeterConsumer.ts`:

```js
import initGreeter from './greeter';

export const greetSomeone = (name: string) => {
  const greeter = initGreeter();
  greeter.sayHello(name);
};
```

`greeterConsumer.test.ts`:

```js
import initGreeter from './greeter';
import { greetSomeone } from './greeterConsumer';

const mGreeter = {
  sayHello: jest.fn(),
};

jest.mock('./greeter', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => mGreeter);
});

describe('greeterConsumer', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('greeter consumer should call SayHello on greeter', () => {
    greetSomeone('sam');
    expect(initGreeter).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mGreeter.sayHello).toBeCalledWith('sam');
  });

  it('greeter consumer throws exception', () => {
    mGreeter.sayHello.mockImplementationOnce(() => {
      throw new Error('oops');
    });
    expect(() => greetSomeone('sam')).toThrowError('oops');
    expect(initGreeter).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mGreeter.sayHello).toBeCalledWith('sam');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65281989/greeterConsumer.test.ts
  greeterConsumer
    ✓ greeter consumer should call SayHello on greeter (3 ms)
    ✓ greeter consumer throws exception (10 ms)

--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File                | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files           |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 greeterConsumer.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
--------------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.473 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/65281989

Comment: Thanks @slideshowp2 for the detailed response. unfortunately, I am getting the error "TypeError: greeter_1.default is not a function" from the test "greeter consumer should call SayHello on greeter". Please see details in the update section of op. 
Is there some config settings for jest messing this up on my side?

Comment: Looks like I was able to get this working. Please see update 2 in OP. Thanks again for the detailed response @slideshowp2.

Comment: Error: This is a precaution to guard against uninitialized mock variables. If it is ensured that the mock is required lazily, variable names prefixed with `mock` (case insensitive) are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

I use below to mock logger , which return logger instance with logging methods

```
jest.mock('logging', () => ({
  getLogger: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
  error: jest.fn(),
  debug: jest.fn(),
  info: jest.fn(),
  warn: jest.fn(),
})
}
));
```